# Error received from database was #1064 - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple MySQL query that I use in PHP but it gives me this error;

**Database query failed. Error received from database was #1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 3 for the query: SELECT *
FROM mantis_user_table
WHERE email LIKE '%me%'.**

```
 $t_user_table = db_get_table( 'mantis_user_table' );   
 $temp_mail = '%' . $p_email . '%';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM $t_user_table WHERE email LIKE '{$temp_mail}'";
 $result = db_query_bound( $query, Array( $p_realname ) );
```

The thing I can not understand is, when I run it in phpmyadmin, it gives me the correct values.
So can you please help me with this situation ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

This is the code that I use while editing :

```
$File = "c:/YourFile.txt";
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
$Data = $query;
fwrite($Handle, $Data);
fclose($Handle);
```

Here you can see the query that I get when I write :

```
SELECT * FROM mantis_user_table WHERE email LIKE '%meh%'
```

And this query normally gives me some results in phpmyadmin , now I dont have any result on web site

And if you want this is the rest of the code that returns the id of the selected item:

```
$result = db_query_bound( $query, Array( $temp_mail ) );
if( 0 == db_num_rows( $result ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    $row = db_fetch_array( $result );
    user_cache_database_result( $row );
    return $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Look at the final query (`echo $query`). What does it look like?

Comment: @Pekka웃 SELECT * FROM mantis_user_table WHERE email LIKE '%me%', so this is the same as I posted here

Comment: And some consistency on use on inline variables might be worth mentioning. You use three different approaches in two lines...

Comment: Can you show the full code you are using?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I edited the entry, please take a look

Comment: @markdwhite sorry but I did not get what you said, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but why are you passing what looks like a parameter into a parameterless query with your `db_query_bound()` function?  It may be either trying to apply a bound variable where none is needed or `$p_realname` may be null.

Comment: @mehmetozer - it doesn't help with your issue, but you've used . to concat $p_email, then wrapped $t_user_table in double quotes, and wrapped $temp_mail in braces. It's just a bit cleaner to use one consistent approach. Just an observation - not trying to be picky.

Comment: @Crontab might be, so what you are telling that I should not use $p_realname there ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.  I don't know what `db_query_bound()` actually does or what parameters it expects, so I'm just guessing.  Try to completely omit the second argument when you call that function and see if it works.

Comment: @Crontab yeah u were right, it did solve the problem of 'NULL' thing of MySQL but now it does not give me the result even there must be lots of results

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the `{}` characters in your match?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ it doesnt change anything

Comment: What do you get when you copy and past the query string (from `echo $query;`) directly into a database connector?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I got the good result

Comment: Edit your post and include the code you're using to display your query results.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a loop of some sort to get *all* the results?  I'm making the assumption that `db_fetch_array()` only returns a single row.

Comment: @Crontab I just need the first one, so thats why it doesnt matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM $t_user_table WHERE email LIKE "{$temp_mail}"';
```

(some versions of mysql don't recognize ' symbol)